# Converting docker-compose to a helm chart?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, kubernetes-helm

I have a docker-compose file containing 2 images to a security tool I am using. My challenge is to convert it into helm chart consisting of deployment.yaml and service.yaml. The docker-compose looks like this -

```
  version: '3'

  services:

  nginx:
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    environment:
      - NG_SERVER_NAME=192.168.1.228
    links:
      - tomcat8
    image: continuumsecurity/iriusrisk-prod:nginx-prod-ssl
    container_name: iriusrisk-nginx
    volumes:
      - "./cert.pem:/etc/nginx/ssl/star_iriusrisk_com.crt"
      - "./key.pem:/etc/nginx/ssl/star_iriusrisk_com.key"

  tomcat8:
    environment:
      - IRIUS_DB_URL=jdbc\:postgresql\://192.168.1.228\:5432/iriusprod?user\=iriusprod&password\=alongandcomplexpassword2523
      - IRIUS_EDITION=saas
      - IRIUS_EXT_URL=http\://192.168.1.228
      - grails_env=production
    image: continuumsecurity/iriusrisk-prod:tomcat8-2
    container_name: iriusrisk-tomcat8
```

There is a postgres server running too which I am able to convert into a helm chart and expose it to my ip (192.168.1.228) on port 5432. But for the iriusrisk and tomcat image which are linked to each other, I am not able to it figure out. This has been my solution for the deployment file for both.

deployment-tomcat.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: tomcat
  labels:
    app: {{ .Values.tomcat.app.name }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.tomcat.replicas }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .Values.tomcat.app.name }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ .Values.tomcat.app.name }}
    spec:
      {{- if .Values.tomcat.imagePullSecretsName }}
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: {{ .Values.tomcat.imagePullSecretsName }}
      {{- end}}
      restartPolicy: Always
      serviceAccountName: {{ .Values.tomcat.serviceAccountName }}

      containers:
      - name: {{ .Values.tomcat.app.name }}
        image: "{{ .Values.tomcat.ImageName }}:{{ .Values.tomcat.ImageTag }}"
        container_name: iriusrisk-tomcat8
        imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.tomcat.ImagePullPolicy }}
        ports:
        - containerPort: {{ .Values.tomcat.port }}
        env:
          - name: IRIUS_DB_URL
            value: jdbc\:postgresql\://192.168.1.228\:5432/iriusprod?user\=iriusprod&password\=alongandcomplexpassword2523
          - name: IRIUS_EDITION
            value: saas
          - name: IRIUS_EXT_URL
            value: http\://192.168.1.228
          - name: grails_env
            value: production
```

deployment-iriusrisk.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: iriusrisk
  labels:
    app: {{ .Values.iriusrisk.app.name }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.iriusrisk.replicas }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .Values.iriusrisk.app.name }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ .Values.iriusrisk.app.name }}
    spec:
      {{- if .Values.iriusrisk.imagePullSecretsName }}
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: {{ .Values.iriusrisk.imagePullSecretsName }}
      {{- end}}
      restartPolicy: Always
      serviceAccountName: {{ .Values.iriusrisk.serviceAccountName }}

      containers:
      - name: {{ .Values.iriusrisk.app.name }}
        image: "{{ .Values.iriusrisk.ImageName }}:{{ .Values.iriusrisk.ImageTag }}"
        container_name: iriusrisk-nginx
        imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.iriusrisk.ImagePullPolicy }}
        ports:
        - containerPort: {{ .Values.iriusrisk.port }}
        env:
          - name: NG_SERVER_NAME
            value: "192.168.1.228"
        volumes: 
          - "./cert.pem:/etc/nginx/ssl/star_iriusrisk_com.crt"
          - "./key.pem:/etc/nginx/ssl/star_iriusrisk_com.key"
```

How should I go around solving this issue? I have looked at "linking" pods with each other but none of the solutions I tried worked. I am bit new to this hence I am still a bit confused about how to expose pods and connect to each other.

Comment: "Link" doesn't really mean anything even in current Docker.  In Kubernetes you almost always need a [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) to route connections to a pod, even between pods.  I would expect this setup to need two Deployments, two Services, and one Secret.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to figure my yaml files for deployments and services.

Answer (score 55):

The [kompose](https://kompose.io/) tool now includes the ability to convert to Helm charts from docker-compose.yml files:

`kompose convert -c`

Check out the kompose [Alternative Conversions](https://kompose.io/user-guide/#alternative-conversions) documentation (also [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kompose/blob/master/docs/user-guide.md#alternative-conversions)).

Comment: That link to alternative conversions points to a deadend.

Comment: @JuanJimenez That's odd. The link was live when I checked just now.

Comment: I wonder if it got hammered by the Fastly CDN outage.

Comment: The kompose.io site seems to be down at the moment. But the docs are also available at their github page. I added a link to my answer above.

Answer (score 3):

From my current knowledge, there is no such tool is developed or published that converts helm-chart into docker-compose file. But the conversion from `docker-compose` to kubernetes resource manifests can be done by using tool like [kompose](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/translate-compose-kubernetes/) (https://kompose.io).

Comment: Thanks. I will have a look at the tool.

Comment: Do we have something to convert helm charts to docker-compose files . We need for our dev env which does not have support for kubernetes, but we need to reuse our helm charts

Comment: @Tiny In that case it needs to write custom one.

Comment: @ShudiptaSharma - Any tool which can be used ?

Comment: I don't know about such a tool yet. But I wanna to have one. Which means need to write such a one.

Comment: kompose now includes a [helm chart conversion](https://kompose.io/user-guide/#alternative-conversions) option `kompose convert -c`

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not necessary to convert from helm chart to docker-compose. You can use Minikube to run whatever is needed locally. Otherwise, the other  alternative is to run your containers locally and reverse engineer. i.e. produce the docker compose file. Here is a link to GitHub that does this for you https://github.com/Red5d/docker-autocompose.

Good Luck